# When creating a foreign key in firebird, the error violation of the FOREIGN KEY restriction "PK_ROLES1" in the "roles" table comes out?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird1.5

I am trying to create a foreign key in the user_roles table.It has a user_id and a roles_id. I created a foreign key for user_id. And for roles_id it is not possible to create. I work at ibexpert.
An error comes out: violation of FOREIGN KEY constraint "PK_RULES 1" on table "rules".I will be glad of any help.

```sql
alter table "users_roles"
add constraint FK_USERS_ROLES_2
foreign key (ROLE_ID)
references "roles"(ID)
on delete CASCADE
on update CASCADE
using index FK_USERS_ROLES_2
```

Comment: Table "rules" mentioned in the error text and table "users_roles" mentioned in the query are two different tables?..

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with the tables you defined, sample content, and the statement which results in the error. As an aside, Firebird 1.5 has been out of support since 2009. You should really consider upgrading.

Comment: It is also odd to have a foreign key name starting with `PK_`, maybe you defined something wrong in table `"rules"`.